# SDL Experience Optimization 8 is not tracking with GA

Tags: smarttarget, experience-optimization

I have configured SDL Experience Optimization 8 on SDL Web 8.1.1 with DXA 1.4.
Along with GA as per SDL online document.

When I configured Experiments in CMS as per image below, I am able to get random promotions on the DXA demo site home page, also redirect link is working fine on the promotional component, But still I am not getting anything tracked in my GA account, also not getting any error in any logs.

[image]

Analytics settings in Management/Query/Session Service is as below:

> ```
>     <Analytics implementationClass="com.tridion.smarttarget.analytics.google.GoogleAnalyticsManager" timeoutMilliseconds="5000" trackingRedirectUrl="/redirect/">
>         <ServiceAccountEmailAddress>**</ServiceAccountEmailAddress>
>         <PrivatekeyPath>/app/GoogleKey/***</PrivatekeyPath>
>         <AccountId>***</AccountId>
>         <TrackingId>UA-8792***</TrackingId>
>         <ViewId>134***</ViewId>
>         <CustomDimensions>
>             <ExperimentId>dimension1</ExperimentId>
>             <InstanceId>dimension2</InstanceId>
>             <PublicationId>dimension3</PublicationId>
>             <PageId>dimension4</PageId>
>             <Region>dimension5</Region>
>             <ComponentId>dimension6</ComponentId>
>             <ComponentTemplateId>dimension7</ComponentTemplateId>
>             <ChosenVariant>dimension8</ChosenVariant>
>         </CustomDimensions>
>     </Analytics>
> ```

If anyone faced similar issue please provide suggestions where should I missed.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: I have followed SDL online document for setting up GA account and integration.Is there any settings that we missed, due to that GA is not tracking any data for the experiences that I have created in CMS  targetting?

Comment: @Piuush: Can you please share the logs, also double check ga account link is working inside the server sometime could be issue with firewall